# Add live text from input field to another div with Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field with Add button below it. Also have another Div class named .new-option-content
What I am trying to do is if anyone type something in the input filed and click the +ADD button this text of the input filed will append with a Check box inside .new-option-content div.

Here is the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/has9L9Lh/2/)**

I tried with this but I guess with this process I can't  get the result.

```
$( ".checklist-new-item-text" )
  .keyup(function() {
    var value = $( this ).val();
    $( ".new-option-content" ).text( value );
  })
  .keyup();
```

I am not good with advance jquery. I did tried to find something similar but failed. I am not sure if this can be done with jquery.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want to do?

Comment: One more version http://jsfiddle.net/has9L9Lh/7/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/has9L9Lh/6/
You can see here what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#add").click(function(){

   var newLabel = $("#optionInput").val();

   if (!newLabel) return; //avoid adding empty checkboxes
   var newOption = '<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox">' + newLabel +'</label></div>';   

   $(".new-option-content").append(newOption);

   $("#optionInput").val(''); //clearing value

})
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/has9L9Lh/8/

If you want to use it in multiple places on your page, you can try this modified version:

```
$(".new-option-add").click(function(){

   var labelInput = $(this).parent().parent().find(".checklist-new-item-text")
   var newLabel = labelInput.val()

   if (!newLabel) return; //avoid adding empty checkboxes

   var newOption = '<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox">' + newLabel +'</label></div>';   

   // where to append? 
   var listToAppend = $(this).attr("data")

    $("." + listToAppend).append(newOption); 

   labelInput.val(''); //clearing value

})
```

We are using data attribute value on the button, to assign class name of the list, which need to be updated.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/has9L9Lh/18/

Comment: /* clean input value after */ $("#optionInput").val('');

Comment: One question here. If I have this in multiple places on my page how can I use this ? because you use ID for add button and input field.
Is there any way so that this can be use multiple time in a page ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it:

```
$(function() {
    $('.new-option-add').on('click',function() {
        var noc = $('.new-option-content'),
            val = $('.checklist-new-item-text');
        !val.val() || noc.append( 
            $('<div/>',{class:'checkbox'}).html(
                $('<label/>').html( $('<input/>', {type:'checkbox'}) )
                .append( ' ' )
                .append( val.val() )
            )
        );
        val.val('');
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/has9L9Lh/11/)

And this should work for multiple sections:

```
$(function() {
    $('.new-option-add').on('click',function() {
        var section = $(this).closest('section'),
            noc = $('.new-option-content', section),
            val = $('.checklist-new-item-text', section);
        !val.val() || noc.append( 
            $('<div/>',{class:'checkbox'}).html(
                $('<label/>').html( $('<input/>', {type:'checkbox'}) )
                .append( ' ' )
                .append( val.val() )
            )
        );
        val.val('');
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/has9L9Lh/14/)

Comment: If I have this in multiple places on my page how can I use this ? I see with your code help if I repeat same and add from any input it append all of them. 
EX: http://jsfiddle.net/has9L9Lh/13/

Is this possible to make it work for couple of same in one single page ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, by creating context with, say, `section` elements and adjusting the code as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/has9L9Lh/14/

Answer (score 1):

Many have answered, yet another option is to use `.clone()`, cause otherwise you can end up in a maintainence nightmare, so something like

```
$(".new-option-add").click(function() {
    var checkbox = $(".checkbox:first").clone(), value;
    value = $(".checklist-new-item-text").val();
    checkbox.html(checkbox.html().replace('Sample 1', value));
    checkbox.appendTo($(".new-option-content"));
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/has9L9Lh/19/

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by adding this code

on click event

```
 $('#yourDiv').append(' <label><input id="chkbox" type="checkbox"> "+$('#yourText').val() +" </label>');
```

Comment: This will never work if you don't add a click event listener to 'add' button.

Comment: try it of course in click event and its better to use (id) for created elements